# Rails order collection by attribute of associated model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, associations, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to figure out a way to order a model's collection based on an attribute of an association of the collected model (I think... what a mouthful). Here's what I'm doing:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, :order => :category_id
end
```

At the moment `order.items` returns the Items ordered by the category_id. But what I really want is to have them listed by alphabetical **`category.name`**. Is that possible?

Thanks,
Stewart

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should work if you use :include to eager load the categories.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, :include => :categories, :order => "categories.name"
end
```